# Most Important Stat Theory Concepts -- Interview

Tags: probability, data-mining, mathematical-statistics

I have an interview with a top company for a data scientist position.   I was made aware that they will be testing probability/statistical theory concepts.

So the question:

If you had 1 hour tops to do an all-inclusive interview about a range of topics, and wanted to test someone's knowledge of probability/statistical theory as well.... what concepts would you test?

Another way of phrasing the question:

What are the most important concepts to know from probability/statistical theory?

(I can't study everything!)

Comment: Questions like this are a little problematic. They don't have single, factual answers, but tend to elicit opinions. That is considered a reason for closing a question as off-topic (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), note that CV is not intended as a discussion forum. I do think this is a gray area, & that there is some room for questions like this. At a minimum, you should make this Q community wiki, but be aware that it may still be closed.

Comment: They're probably less interested in testing your knowledge of
probability/statistical theory concepts (that's what academic qualifications are for) than in your ability to apply them to real-life problems. So be prepared to talk about such applications - in your previous jobs, your post-graduate theses, & in the job you hope to be doing.